# Html BeginForm is not passing the value from View to controller in ASP.Net MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, razor, file-upload

In My .NET MVC3 razor PROJECT i have to implement Image upload .Here my problem is that when i click the upload button its just refreshing the page.

My view Code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadPhoto", "Home",FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                    {
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                            Customer ID</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CusId, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>

                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                            Customer Name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="id" />
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                                    DMIT Image</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                     @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.CusId)
                                     @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Name)
                                    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Upload" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
```

This is the change in address bar when i click on the submit button

> http:// /Home/FileUpload?CusId=1&Name=Nidheesh&CusId=1&Name=Nidheesh&file=Customer.JPG#

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult UploadPhoto()
        {
            return View();
        }



        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadPhoto(ElixiCustPro elixi, HttpPostedFileBase uploadfile, int CusId,string Name)
        {
            try
            {
                if (uploadfile != null && uploadfile.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    if ((uploadfile.ContentType == "image/jpeg") || (uploadfile.ContentType == "image/gif") || (uploadfile.ContentType == "image/png"))//check allow jpg, gif, png
                    {
                        elixi.Image = new byte[uploadfile.ContentLength];
                        uploadfile.InputStream.Read(elixi.Image, 0, uploadfile.ContentLength);
                        var filename = Path.GetFileName(uploadfile.FileName);
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ElixirFiles/UploadImagesElixir/"), filename);
                        uploadfile.SaveAs(path);

                        ecp.Image = new byte[uploadfile.ContentLength];
                        ecp.ImageUrl = path;
                        ecp.CustomerName = Name;
                        ecp.CusId = CusId;
                        ment.ElixiProData.Add(ecp);
                        ment.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("ScanManagement");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View(ex.Message.ToString());
            }


            return View();
        }
```

aspx.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

Comment: Does the request reach the controller? If yes, can you show its code?

Comment: No its not reaching ...I will show my controller code

Comment: Also it looks like you have custom routes. It would be good to see them as well

Comment: When i click the upload button it refresh the page with change in address bar that  http:// /Home/FileUpload?CusId=1&Name=Nidheesh&CusId=1&Name=Nidheesh&file=Customer.JPG#

Comment: Let's put it like this. In your project you have file `Global.asax.cs`, which contains method `RegisterRoutes`. Can you post this method?

Comment: @Andrei i have updated the same in question

Comment: Something is causing your form to submit via GET even though you've initially set it to POST. Since the GET action just returns the view, you're never getting anywhere. It's probably some stray JS somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of modifications required in your code to make it working.

1. There is no need of parameters like - int CusId,string Name. They are already included in the model.
2. You HttpPostedFileBase name should be 'file', which should be equivalent to name of input=file type. Or else you will get null.

So working code would be -

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadPhoto(ElixiCustPro elixi, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    return null;
}
```

The other parts of code which I used is as follows -

Model -

```
public class ElixiCustPro
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CusId { get; set; }    
}
```

GET Action -

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UploadPhoto()
{
    ElixiCustPro p = new ElixiCustPro();
    return View(p);
}
```

View -

```
@model MVC.Controllers.ElixiCustPro

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadPhoto", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
            Customer ID
        </label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CusId, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>

        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
            Customer Name
        </label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="id" />
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                DMIT Image
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CusId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
                <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Upload" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

output -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some modification in your code.

1. Name of "HttpPostedFileBase" parameter is same as input type file name. In your case you need to use **file** as "**HttpPostedFileBase**" parameter name.
2. If you are using Model than no need to pass parameters those are already in Model like **CusId, Name**